# Avoid deep nesting code in grouping logic

Tags: php, group-by, refactoring

I need some advice or recommended practices here.

I have a multiple field (six or more) group by SQL query. I'm getting the expected results in the right order.

My default approach to this is to iterate over the ordered results saving the last loop element to test it on next iteration. If it changed then I add it to the resulting list and move on. I think this is a common way to solve this kind of problem.

Up to two fields the I think my approach is fine. But when I group by more than two fields it seems overcomplicated. The code begins to rot and looks difficult to maintain as the number of nested conditions grows.

Is there a better way at all to accomplish this?

My default approach (one field)

```
    $groupOne = null;
    $lastId = null;
    $result = array();

    foreach($orderedData as $item) {
        if ($lastId !== $item['id']) {
            if ($groupOne !== null) {
                $resultList[] = $groupOne;
            }
            $groupOne = new stdClass();
        }

        //rest of the logic

        $lastId = $item['id'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found a better way. In the beginning of loop instead of validating all the group breaks I just validate the last one. If the last one changed then it's logical that all other ones before must be updated too. This simplifies my code. But I'm always open to suggestions and other examples. Thanks.